# Setting classpath for Java

Tags: java

I was trying to use a tool a tool written in java called "fastqc" (for people who are interested in [what is fastqc](http://www.bioinformatics.babraham.ac.uk/projects/fastqc/). 
when I tried typing the command :" fastqc" 
I got the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: uk/ac/babraham/FastQC/FastQCApplication
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: uk.ac.babraham.FastQC.FastQCApplication
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:323)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:268)
```

when someone had similar previously,[some one suggested that in similar case, I need to set the class path to the directory which contains FastQC installation](http://www.bioinformatics.babraham.ac.uk/projects/fastqc/):

and depending on having a standard class path or non-standard classpath on my machine, I need to append existing classpath like:

```
java -Xmx250m -classpath /usr/local/FastQC uk.ac.bbsrc.babraham.FastQC.FastQCApplication
```

or

```
java -Xmx250m -classpath /usr/local/FastQC:$CLASSPATH uk.ac.bbsrc.babraham.FastQC.FastQCApplication
```

Since my directory which contains the FastQC is 
/u32/myusername/Tool/FastQC

so I tried both:

```
java -Xmx250m -classpath /u32/myusername/Tool/FastQC uk.ac.bbsrc.babraham.FastQC.FastQCApplication
```

and

```
java -Xmx250m -classpath /u32/myusername/Tool/FastQC:$CLASSPATH uk.ac.bbsrc.babraham.FastQC.FastQCApplication
```

but none of them seemed to work.

Did I mess something up?  I am not sure about what `-Xmx250m` means, with or without it, the path setting did not work. 
Sorry for my ignorance. Any idea or suggestion appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. well the easy step to do is go to install folder
2. copy the address of `bin` folder
3. open "My computer properties" -> "Advanced system setting" -> "Environment variables"
4. click on "New" and paste that address and name it as path if the address is in the bin and put `;`
5. again, click "New", paste the address, remove `bin` and insert `lib` and name it as `classpath`
6. put `;` after end
7. restart cmd
8. open cmd check by typing `javac`

That's it